# Is being an isosceles triangle a necessary condition to be an equilateral one?

Tags: geometry, logic

> Is being an isosceles triangle a necessary condition to be an equilateral one?

I really don't know the answer, but I think it's "no" since to be a equilateral one, it must has all the sides with the same length.

Comment: $A$ is a necessary condition for $B$ means $B \implies A$ (or $\neg A \implies \neg B$).

Comment: I think you're confusing **necessary** with **sufficient**. Replace necessary with sufficient in your question and then the answer you give is correct, OP.

Something is necessary means you need it to be true, or you require it to be true, in order for another condition to be met. So your question can be re-stated as: "in order for a triangle to be equilateral, do you require it to be isosceles?"

Related: Sufficient means enough. So a triangle being isosceles is not sufficient for it to be equilateral.

Comment: Either that, or you're reading the question stated, "Is being an isosceles triangle a necessary condition to be an equilateral one?" as the different question, "If I've got an isosceles triangle, is it necessarily an equilateral one?", which in fact is the same as the first question with necessary replaced with sufficient, like in my previous paragraph. So I've got a feeling that your interpretation of the semantic meaning of the question is incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An isosceles triangle has at least two sides of the same length. Also, an equilateral triangle has all three sides of the same length. So yes, any equilateral triangle is also isosceles. This means that being isosceles is necessary for being equilateral (and being equilateral is sufficient for being isosceles).